# How to fix and error cause by unknown mediator iso8583 in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, iso8583

hi everyone i try to use iso8583 connector in WSO2 ESB, i already follow this link but still got an error  even i copied all the source exactly the same like in this link https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/ISO8583-connector/ISO8583-inbound-endpoint-example/ anyone can give me solutions about it ?

this is the error i always got when i run the project
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}iso8583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that the ESB cannot find the connector during the runtime.

You can verify whether the connector is properly deployed if the connector name is visible in /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/imports. If the connector is not available you need to add the connector to the ESB runtime.

You need to download the connector from the store[1] and add it to the ESB through the management console under connectors --> Add.

You can also add the connector through a connector exporter project[2] if you are deploying services using a car application.

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/e4cf3fd5-445f-4317-beb6-09998906fb0d

[2] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/develop/creating-artifacts/adding-connectors/

Comment: thank you for your answer Mrs @Imedhya osandi Weerasinghe it's work for me with the second solutions of yours.